# What is my bedrock?

Tags: internal-consistency, earth-like, geology

I'm looking for a rock from which my island is constructed. It needs to be:

- Either created from the sea or via intense pressure/heat
- Capable of trapping layers of gas beneath it
- White(ish)

I was thinking about limestone but I'm not sure if islands with large quantities of limestone are realistic. Also could a softer rock such as limestone trap large quantities of natural gas (methane and hydrogen) beneath the surface?

Comment: What do you need the trapped gases for?  I should have asked that first.  What gas and how it is distributed may play a large role.

Comment: The lighter-than-air gas is part of the island's industry/economy. I'd like the rock to be white as I'd like it to resemble greek/roman architecture.

Comment: Would high levels of Helium ok?  Hydrogen would often be easier to get via metals, reforming from hydrocarbons, or Hydrolysis and that kind of misses the point as they aren't mined.  I had been thinking regular trapped air.  There aren't any other lighter than air gases except barely pure nitrogen.

Comment: Nevermind, just wrote my peace for each.

Comment: Actually Greek/Roman architecture was not white at all. It's just that the colour was washed off of them over the millennia so the remains are white now.

Comment: @celtschk True but the look is beautiful and iconic to us now.  It is reasonable to think that he would want his fictional setting to look like that.

Comment: @kaine helium is great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Previous answer aimed for trapped air

You want something that contains feldspar and/or quartz to make it light and granite often does but its color varys based on the source. You want it to be rapidly cooled igneous rock.  I have a hard time seeing how something high in carbonates could survive in the ocean long term as water would degrade carbonates over time. you could possibly make the same arguement with feldspars but they will hold up better than carbonates.

Felsite is high silica igneous rock. igneous rock can have cavities depending on the way it cools (see pummice).  It contains large quantities of quartz which is, of course, white.  Noe though that rhyolite is often a type of this and the rhyolite I mine is pink.

Pumice is, of course, porous and light but not as light as Felsite.

Tonalite looks exactly the right appearance but is rare enough I don't think you will find a whole island of it.

If you want a volcano on the island, you want a volcanic igneous rock.  If you don't want there to have every been volcanic activity, you want a plutonic rock.

Sedimentary rocks will be too soft and porous for you. (Pores trap things but can let things slip through expecially gases)

Metamorphic rock will prevent trapped gasses.

### New answer for lighter than air gases

While most of the above holds true, it doesn't allow for why trapped gases are there.

There are two lighter than air gases: Hydrogen and Helium.

Hydrogen does not get trapped as a gas in rock much at all.  It is, however, common in chemicals that can be mined.  Hydrocarbons are trapped in sedimentary rocks and are made of carbon and hydrogen.  While buring these causes the oxygen to react with the hydrogen producing water, reforming these to make double bonds/soot/etc. by heating in a oxygen free environment can cause hydrogen to be released but it is still reactive so... yeah.. do some research. With some oxygen present, this can be done with out input electricity. Hydrogen can be produced easily by passing an electric current through water.  This is hydolysis and is the most likely way to make lighter than air gas on an island.  As natural gas is often mined from the sedimentary rock at the ocean floor, it doesn't matter what you bedrock is much does it?  Choose any very high silica igneous rock to make the island more stable and volcanic or some kind of sandstone or marble and say it happend via an upheval.

Helium can actually be mined as a gas but is far more rare than hydrogen.  Almost all of the helium on earth was formed by the radioactive decay of uranium.  There needs, therefore, to be a deep bedrock of high urnaium granite.  The helium diffuses through grain boundaries (i think) in the granites into areas with a higher porosity (often sedimentary rocks).  If you want an island (kind of hard as helium would want to get into the water), propose the following. You have a high silica/high uranium baserock that is heated and coming to the surface as magma (but I don't actually want it to become lava).  Above this is a metamorphic upheval brought up by the tentonic activity which is marble.  This marble is chosen so they can form it as the greeks/romans did.  The other white alternative are harder to sculpt.  Water leaking beneath the marble at some point caused an area of the lava to cool quickly and form a porous region.  This is now largely sealed by the lava flow.  Radioactive decay of the uranium forms helium gas which concentrates in the porous region of the rock under the largely non-porous marble.

Comment: Sorry just for clarification "Metamorphic rock will prevent trapped gasses." prevent escaping or prevent them being formed?

Comment: Both. They are in general non-porous.  They will prevent them escaping but you don't have a obvious means of them getting under there.

Answer (score 1):

Natrocarbonatite is a rare form of lava (only known to come from a volcano in Tanzania). It bubbles to the surface as a muddy black color, and then turns white as it cools.

Theoretically, if such a volcano existed in under the sea, perhaps an entire island could be made out of it.

Comment: So it is clear, this contains sodium and potassium carbonates which are water soluble.  It seems like this would not make sense as an island.